# CKRecord setValue:forKey or setObject:forKey

Tags: swift, cloudkit, ckrecord

The `CKRecord` class specification in Swift says to use `setObject:forKey:` to set the value of a `CKRecord`. But I am seeing a lot of code examples with `setValue:forKey:` which is part of `NSValueCoding` protocol. So can someone explain what is the advantage of one over the other?

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately `setValue:` is **very** often misused.

Easy Rule:

**The designated method to set an object for a key in a key/value collection type is `setObject:` or key subscription.**

`setValue:` is a key-value-coding method with a special meaning. For example you can set the same property of all dictionaries (or custom objects) in an array simultaneously with a single line. `setValue:` can also be used to set a property in a custom class by literal key rather than using the appropriate setter.

For example the syntax

```
object.name = "foo"
```

and

```
object.setValue("foo", forKey:"name")
```

does basically the same.

One of the exceptions to use `setValue:` is `NSManagedObject` because this class relies heavily on key-value-coding.

**Edit:**

Summary (literal quotation of rmaddy's excellent comment, thanks):

**Only use `setValue:forKey:` when you have a clear, specific need to use key-value coding.**

Comment: tl;dr - Only use `setValue:forKey:` when you have a clear, specific need to use key-value coding.